# unable to bind viewmodel with knockout

Tags: asp.net, knockout.js

I am trying to use knockout.js to simlessly bind object to a view; however, 
I have come to a point where I do not understand what is happening...
For some reason My view is not getting bound.  On my page I have a dropdown with list of product categories.  Once a category has been changed I want to populate html table with products information that belong to the selected category.

Following is the code I am using.

HTML:

```
    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlProductCategory" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static">
    </asp:DropDownList>
    <div id="divProducts">
        <table width='100%' border="1">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th width='25%'>
                    Product ID
                </th>
                <th width='25%'>
                    Product Name
                </th>
                <th width='15%'>
                    Supplier ID
                </th>
                <th width='10%'>
                    Category ID
                </th>
                <th>
                    QuantityPerUnit
                </th>
                <th>
                    UnitPrice                    
                </th>
                <th>
                     UnitsInStock
                </th>
                <th>
                     UnitsOnOrder
                </th>                    
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody data-bind="foreach: Products">
           <tr>
                <td>
                    <span data-bind="text: ProductID"> </span>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <span data-bind="text: ProductName"> </span>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <span data-bind="text: SupplierID"> </span>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <span data-bind="text: CategoryID"> </span>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <span data-bind="text: QuantityPerUnit"> </span>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <span data-bind="text: UnitPrice"> </span>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <span data-bind="text: UnitsInStock"> </span>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <span data-bind="text: UnitsOnOrder"> </span>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <a href='#' data-bind='click: $parent.removeLine'>Remove</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    </div>
```

On the server .NET JavaScriptSerializer object to get json representation of
the list of product objects:

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = System.Web.Script.Services.ResponseFormat.Json)]
public object ProcessRequest(string oData)
{
    // Some code to get listOfProducts
    var json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(listOfProducts);
    return json;
}
```

Here is my ViewModel object:

```
function ProductsListViewModel (bindingData) {
    var self = this;  

    this.Products = {};

    //////////////////////////////////////////////
    // Load
    /////////////////////////////////////////////
    this.BindViewModel = function (jsonProducts) {
        var _bindingData = jsonProducts;

        if (_bindingData && ObjectTypeChecker.IsJsonObject(_bindingData)) {
            _bindingData = $.parseJSON(_bindingData);
        }

        if (_bindingData && _bindingData.d) {
            _bindingData = eval(_bindingData.d);
        }

        self.Products = _bindingData;
        ko.mapping.fromJS(self.Products, self);
    };

    this.InitialLoad = function()
    {
        var _bindingData = bindingData;

        if (_bindingData && ObjectTypeChecker.IsJsonObject(_bindingData)) {
            _bindingData = $.parseJSON(_bindingData);
        }

        if (_bindingData && _bindingData.d) {
            _bindingData = eval(_bindingData.d);
        }

        self.Products = _bindingData;

        ko.mapping.fromJS(self.Products, {});
    }

    this.InitialLoad();

    ////////////////// STATIC METHODS ////////////////////////////
    ProductsListViewModel.GetCurrentModel = function () {
        return self;
    }
};
```

On the client, at first load I am initializing my viewmodel with empty values getting "metadata" for the object from server which works perfectly fine:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    // Call server for metadata
    var agent = new WtrStpJsAgent("WtrStpWireHandler", "NorthwindActionHandler",   "GetMetadata", ["Products"]);
    var jsonProducts = agent.GetMetadata();

    // Now Load initial state for viewmodel
    LoadModels();
});


// Load metadata for all viewmodels
function LoadModels() {
    var agent = new WtrStpJsAgent("WtrStpWireHandler", "NorthwindActionHandler",  "GetMetadata", ["Products"]);
    var jsonProducts = agent.GetMetadata();

    // Load ProductListViewModel //////////////////////////////////
    myProductsViewModel = new ProductsListViewModel(jsonProducts);
    ko.applyBindings(myProductsViewModel);
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

}
```

After that whenever value in dropdown has changed I call JQuery.ajax method to get product information and I am trying to bind returned data to the View:

```
 // Event Handler for Categories Drpdown
 function onCategoryChange(event) {
    // get data
    var agent = new WtrStpJsAgent("WtrStpWireHandler", "NorthwindActionHandler",  event.type, event.eventArgs);
    var jsonProducts = agent.GetProductsByCategory(event.eventArgs);

    // jsonProducts is a list of products in json format:
    // {"d":"  [{\"ProductID\":1,\"ProductName\":\"Chai\",\"SupplierID\":1,\"CategoryID \":1,\"QuantityPerU nit\":\"10 boxes x 20 bags\",\"UnitPrice\":18.0000,\"UnitsInStock\":39,\"UnitsOnOrder\":0},
//        {\"ProductID\":2,\"ProductName\":\"Chang\",\"SupplierID\":1,\"CategoryID\":1,\"QuantityPerUnit\":\"24 - 12 oz bottles\",\"UnitPrice\":19.0000,\"UnitsInStock\":17,\"UnitsOnOrder\":40}]"}

    // Re-bind view
    BindView(jsonProducts);
}


function BindView(jsonProducts) {
    ProductsListViewModel.GetCurrentModel().BindViewModel(jsonProducts);
}
```

PLEASE HELP!

---

This is an update to my previous post.  I found that following works fine:

```
var myProductsViewModel = null;

$(document).ready(function () {
    // Load all models
    LoadModels();
});

function onCategoryChange(event) {
     var agent = new WtrStpJsAgent("WtrStpWireHandler", "NorthwindActionHandler", event.type, event.eventArgs);
     var jsonProducts = agent.GetProductsByCategory(event.eventArgs);
     BindView(jsonProducts);
}


function LoadModels() {
     var agent = new WtrStpJsAgent("WtrStpWireHandler", "NorthwindActionHandler", "GetMetadata", ["Products"]);
     var jsonProducts = agent.GetMetadata();

     // Load ProductListViewModel //////////////////////////////////
     ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
     if (jsonProducts && ObjectTypeChecker.IsJsonObject(jsonProducts)) {
        bbbData = $.parseJSON(jsonProducts);
     }

     if (bbbData && bbbData.d) {
         list = eval(bbbData.d);
     }

     this.Products = list;
     myProductsViewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(this.Products, {});
     ko.applyBindings(myProductsViewModel);

 }

 function BindView(jsonProducts) {

      if (jsonProducts && ObjectTypeChecker.IsJsonObject(jsonProducts)) {
         zzzz = $.parseJSON(jsonProducts);
      }
      if (zzzz && zzzz.d) {
         lllll = eval(zzzz.d);
      }
      this.Products = lllll;
      ko.mapping.fromJS(this.Products, myProductsViewModel);
 }
```

But this does not work:

---

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
     // Load all models
     LoadModels();
 });

 function onCategoryChange(event) {
     var agent = new WtrStpJsAgent("WtrStpWireHandler", "NorthwindActionHandler", event.type, event.eventArgs);
    var jsonProducts = agent.GetProductsByCategory(event.eventArgs);
    BindView(jsonProducts);
 }

 function LoadModels() {
      var agent = new WtrStpJsAgent("WtrStpWireHandler", "NorthwindActionHandler", "GetMetadata", ["Products"]);
      var jsonProducts = agent.GetMetadata();

  // Load ProductListViewModel //////////////////////////////////
      myProductsViewModel = new ProductsListViewModel(jsonProducts);
      ko.applyBindings(myProductsViewModel);
 }

 function BindView(jsonProducts) {
      ProductsListViewModel.GetCurrentModel().BindViewModel(jsonProducts);        
 }
```

However I still want to keep code more granular so I like having JS objects as described in latter solution...  Therefore, any  idea why it does no work????

Still need help please :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using KnockoutJS and want the UI to update whenever a var changes you need to make them observable.

```
function ProductsListViewModel (bindingData) {
var self = this;  

this.Products = ko.observableArray();


//////////////////////////////////////////////
// Load
/////////////////////////////////////////////
this.BindViewModel = function (jsonProducts) {
    var _bindingData = jsonProducts;

    if (_bindingData && ObjectTypeChecker.IsJsonObject(_bindingData)) {
        _bindingData = $.parseJSON(_bindingData);
    }

    if (_bindingData && _bindingData.d) {
        _bindingData = eval(_bindingData.d);
    }

    self.Products(_bindingData);
    ko.mapping.fromJS(self.Products, self);
  };
```

Also take a look at http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observableArrays.html

Comment: Thanks Marthyn for the response I changed definition of Products to be observableArray; however it did not help much...  I still have the same problem...  I think the issue mostly has to do with how objects work in javascript, but can't figure what is wrong...
Strangely enough if I take code inside InitialLoad member and BindViewModel (out of ProductsListViewModel) and put it right into LoadModels and BindView respectively.  Then the solution works fine even without setting Products as observableArray...

Comment: Then i don't know i'm sorry, i am also new to KnockoutJS